# Aligning the text to be at the center of a textfield in Vuetify

Tags: html, css, vue.js, textfield, vuetify.js

I have a read only textfield that shows a string. The string starts from the left side of textfield as it should. I was wondering if there is a way in Vuetify to align the string to the center of textfield?

**UPDATE**
This is my code:

```
<v-text-field
  value="Select the configuration:"
  color="grey lighten-43"
  class="text--darken-3 mt-3 text-xs-center"
  outline
  readonly
  single-line
></v-text-field>
```

Comment: please share your tried work

Comment: Updated the initial question, thanks.

Answer (score 32):

In case you are using scoped styles, a deep selector (i.e. `>>>`) for the input field has to be used:

```
<v-text-field 
  class="centered-input text--darken-3 mt-3" 
  value="Select the configuration:" 
  color="grey lighten-43" 
  outline readonly single-line />
```

```
<style scoped>
    .centered-input >>> input {
      text-align: center
    }
</style>
```

Comment: great finding: deep selector (i.e. >>>) , tks @samwise

Comment: you save me a lot of time. Thank you for this!

Comment: Even w3schools did not mention that. Never saw that either. Nice finding!

Answer (score 11):

The cause of the text being aligned to the left is the base class for `input` that sets `text-align: start`. To solve this add a rule that for that input, for example:

template:

```
<v-text-field 
  class="centered-input text--darken-3 mt-3" 
  value="Select the configuration:" 
  color="grey lighten-43" 
  outline readonly single-line />
```

css:

```css
.centered-input input {
  text-align: center
}
```

```js
new Vue({ el: '#app' })
```

```css
.centered-input input {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.3.5/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.3.5/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="stackoverflow">
    <v-text-field 
      value="Select the configuration:" 
      color="grey lighten-43" 
      class="centered-input text--darken-3 mt-3" 
      outline readonly single-line />
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not working, while another answer a using >>> is

Comment: Strange. Why in some cases `.centered-input input` works (this is working pretty nice for me), but in some cases `.centered-input >>> input` works?

Answer (score 2):

in my case

not working:

```
.centered-input input {
  text-align: center
}
```

working:

```
/deep/ .centered-input input {
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working

```
style="left: auto; right: 0px; position: absolute;"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3, you can use the following syntax:

```
.center-text :deep(input) {
  text-align: center
}
```